# C# Generic Shorthand and Upcasting

Tags: c#, generics

I've been playing with interfaces and generics.

What I want is an `Foo<T>` to be a shorthand for `Foo<T, int>` Is this sensible? Is the following an accepted way of doing it?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Foo<T> : Foo<T, int> where T : class
    {
    }

    public class Foo<T, U> where T : class
    {
        public void Bar()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("this: " + GetType().Name + ", T: " + typeof(T).Name + ", U: " + typeof(U).Name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fooT = new Foo<string>();
            var fooTU = new Foo<string, int>();

            fooT.Bar();
            fooTU.Bar(); 
        }
    }
}
```

What my actual question is... is it possible to up (down?) cast from a `Foo<T, int>` to a `Foo<T>` where `T` is the same type. Does it even make sense to say this, or is this something to do with co/contravariance (which still eludes me)?

To me, a somewhat ignorant human, in this example `Foo<string>` and `Foo<string, int>` are identical types, but of course `((Foo<string>) fooTU).Bar();` does not work!

Comment: It would help if you'd reduce your example as much as possible - if your "actual question" is only about the *classes* `Foo<T, U>` and `Foo<T>`, then don't bother with the interfaces. If you're *actually* interested in the interfaces, please clarify how they're relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What my actual question is... is it possible to up (down?) cast from a `Foo<T, int>` to a `Foo<T>` where T is the same type. Does it even make sense to say this, or is this something to do with co/contravariance (which still eludes me)?

You can cast from `Foo<string, int>` to `Foo<string>` *if* the actual object is of type `Foo<T>`. The fact that they have the same name is completely irrelevant here, so let's change that:

```
class Foo<T, U> {}
class Bar<T> : Foo<T, int>
```

Now:

```
Foo<string, int> foo = new Foo<string, int>();
Bar<string> bar = (Bar<string>) foo; // Bang, throws
```

But:

```
Foo<string, int> foo = new Bar<string>();
Bar<string> bar = (Bar<string>) foo; // This is fine
```

The generics are pretty irrelevant here, really... it's the normal rules of casting.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to up cast from a `Foo<T, int>` to a `Foo<T>` where T is the same type.

Not safely - it's like casting from an `Animal` to a `Dog` - it *might* be a `dog`, but if it's not you're going to get an exception at run-time.

You also cannot take a `Foo<string, int>` and treat it like a `Foo<string>` for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

> in this example Foo and Foo are identical types

This is incorrect. `Foo<T>` is a `Foo<T,int>`, but `Foo<T,int>` is not necessarily a `Foo<T>`. This is why you can cast from `Foo<T>` to `Foo<T,int>`, but not vice-versa.